# How do I exclude a row from a jQuery function?

Tags: jquery

I have a script that deletes a row from a table when a button is clicked:

```
$('.remove').live('click',function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

I need that function to NOT work on rows one and two of the table. On rows 3+ should be removed when that button is clicked. Any ideas?

Comment: You know that `live` has been removed from jQuery ? You should not keep an old version of jQuery, apart if you're sure all your users have old browsers.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better not to show a remove button if the row can't be removed?

Comment: show more code . Which table ? where table code . show us. Don't use live. use On

Comment: @DirkLachowski looks more logical for sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `gt` :

```
$('tr:gt(1) .remove').live('click',function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

But it looks urgent for you to update jQuery to a recent version (where `live` has been suppressed). This would be for example

```
$(document).on('click', 'tr:gt(1) .remove' ,function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: Perfect. I took your second one with the revised script, and it works perfectly! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

.live is deprecate, use on instead like this,

```
$("html").on("click",".remove",function(){
$(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

**UPDATE**
Sorry did not read the question till the end, to exclude row 1 and 2 do like this:

```
$("html").on("click",".remove:gt(1)",function(){
$(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. Is there a way to exclude row 1 and 2 with that script now?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [:gt()](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector:

```
$('tr:gt(1) .remove').live('click',function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

`live()` is deprecated as of jQuery version `1.7`, you should use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.